# AngularJS forms not finding input elements

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

At some point during the development of my app, AngularJS forms stopped working... Yes that means they used to work. That is, form elements are supposed to create their own scope with every `<input />` by their `name`.  However all my forms *are now completely empty*, as if I had no input elements with the name attribute.  Now I can't make any sort of form validation.  I've tried even the most trivial forms and still nothing:

```
<form name="form>
  <input type="text" name="input" required />
</form>
```

Any suggestions as to how to debug this?

Comment: Can you reproduce it with some jsfiddle/plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Hi to do validation your input have to have model directive please see here:   http://jsbin.com/deref/1/edit

```
<form name="form">
          <input type="text" name="foo" required ng-model="input.model"/>
          <span ng-show="form.foo.$error.required">required</span>
    </form>
```

Comment: I tried adding ng-model to the input elements.  Actually, that's how most of my project is setup and the bindings work fine.  It's the "form.foo.$error.required" part that doesn't work.

Comment: @circuitlego can you please post more code from your view, otherwise is difficult to help you

Answer (score 0):

Try **console.log** on the scope

```
console.log($scope.form);
```

If you have your controllers set up correctly, your form should be attached to the scope of controller.

Comment: This is the output -> '{}'

Comment: looks like your $scope is broken somewhere, check if you have correctly open/closed your controllers in html views.